# Show that if n | m, where n and m are integers greater than 1, and if a ≡ b (mod m), where a and b are integers, then a ≡ b (mod n).

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

> Show that if n | m, where n and m are integers greater than 1, and if
>   a ≡ b (mod m), where a and b are integers, then a ≡ b (mod n).

I am wondering if I can show by using any contradiction/contrapositive? 
please guid me how? this is a question on a textbook and I have a test tomorrow.

Thanks^^

Comment: Nothing fancy needed. We are told that $m$ divides $a-b$, and that $n$ divides $m$. So $n$ divides $a-b$.

Comment: omg this is enough for answering on the test right? 'cause you make it looks easier to understand. thanks.

Comment: I   do not know how much detail is expected.  Full detail is given in the two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to give a direct proof. Suppose $n,m,a,b$ are as in your hypothesis. $a\equiv b\pmod x$ is equivalent to $x\mid (b-a)$. Thus, $m\mid(b-a)$, so there is k such that $km = b-a$. Because $n\mid m$, there is $l$ such that $l n = m$. So $k l n = b-a$, which is to say, $n\mid (b-a)$, or in other words $a\equiv b\pmod n$.

More briefly: By hypothesis, $n\mid m$ and $m\mid (b-a)$. The "divides" relation is transitive, so $n\mid (b-a)$ i.e. $a\equiv b\pmod n$.

Comment: could you explain the term" transitive " breifly ?

Comment: It should be fairly easy to guess, and it *is* very easy to [look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) [<-- link], but ok: a relation $R$ is *transitive* $\iff$ for all $x,y,z$, if $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $xRz$.

Comment: thank you. I was just making sure if what I understood is correct. THanks ^^

Comment: No problem, and thank you. After I gave the link, I looked over the wiki article on transitive relations, and noticed that it mentions "divides" as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Since $a\equiv{b}\pmod{m}$ we have $a=mk+b$ where $k\in{\mathbb{Z}}$. Let $tn=m$ then we must have $a=tnk+b$, taking (mod n) gives the desired result.